# How do I load a list of functions from an external R code file?

Tags: r

Here is a R code file (`functions.R`) like this:

```
fun1 <- function(a,b,c) {
...
}

fun2 <- function(a,b,c) {
...
}

fun3 <- function(a,b,c) {
...
}
```

In another code file, how can I create a list that contains the functions defined in `functions.R` with list member names being corresponding function names?

Just like:

```
list(fun1=function(a,b,c){...},fun2=function(a,b,c){...},fun3=function(a,b,c){...})
```

I know `source()` will eventually work but here I don't want to assume that I know the names of functions defined in the external file. I want to directly introduce a list of functions defined in an external R file without knowing what functions are defined in that file.

Comment: I know `source()` will work but I don't want to assume that I know the names of functions defined in that file. I want to directly introduce a list of functions defined in an external R file without knowing what functions are defined in that file. Another way is to write `list(fun1=function(a,b,c){...},...)` in that file and I can directly call `source(...)` to load that file. But it is not what I asked.

Comment: sorry for missing the motivation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
# create new environment
e1 <- new.env()

# source file
sys.source("filename.R", envir = e1)

# find functions
fnames <- ls.str(e1, "function")

# get functions
setNames(mget(fnames, e1), fnames)
```