# R tool to automatically alphabatize functions in a file

Tags: r, refactoring, automated-refactoring

Is this a stackoverflow question?

I have a .R file with 1.3 zillion utility functions that I use. Is there a tool that would magically reorder these alphabetically by name? I haven't been able to find anything.

I *could* roll my own starting with something like

[How do I load a list of functions from an external R code file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798170/how-do-i-load-a-list-of-functions-from-an-external-r-code-file/21798453#21798453)

But if such a tool already exists, I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I don't know any R tool that does this. It would be really nice! But if you're familiar with vim, this works with R functions (at least in my simple test). Worth a shot. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9276110/

Comment: The taglist plugin also looks useful. I use VIM, but not for R coding (except for small things).